# How to create a MYSQL backup with custom names and information

Tags: java, mysql, backup

I need to make a database backup of mysql, but it should have certain features.
The backup should execute on a click of a buttton in java swing.

Path : The path should be declared by me where it is saved (e.g c://backup) but The path should be such that there should be no saving problem if I provide the jar file for my java to some other users, which path is best to use then?

Name : The name will be made up by 3 strings, one is a basic string, other is a Datetime format string followed by 3rd a string again. (e.g. FileName-2012-02-12 09:00:00-Name).

How can I achieve this? Can someone guide me please

I tried to code using mysqldump but still couldnt get it done.

```
String dbName = "dth";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "root";

        String executeCmd = "";
        executeCmd = "mysqldump -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r C:\\backup.sql";

        Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I tried the above code but I couldn't get it done, keeps giving me

> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>   error.

I have tried it by creating a .sql file on the location and still I get the same error.

Comment: The solution has been posted here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924770/simple-backup-and-restore-for-mysql-database-from-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the mysqldump command for that. Maybe you could even call it from whatever program you are writing. The syntax is simple:

`mysqldump -u <user> -h <host> -p<password> <dbname> > <filename>`

this will just put the whole database into that file as an sql script.

Comment: where should be the file saved? so that when I give a jar to someone, it should not give any problems.

Comment: usually i use /tmp because its writable for everybody.