# Backup of the MySQL Database by Java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Well, I'm building a Java program by Netbeans and I need it to back up the whole bank, I have no idea how it does it, I'm new at it.

Comment: Follow these steps:

1. Open IDE

2. Start writing code

3. Read about databases

4. Repeat Step 2 Until you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mysqldump` command:

```
mysqldump --databases mydb > dump.sql
```

more:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html

You can call it from Java using:

```
Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

As described:
[Simple Backup and Restore for mysql Database from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924770/simple-backup-and-restore-for-mysql-database-from-java)